# Mouse right in textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, menustrip

I everyone,

I have development this application, ... my objective is user, if click on right side of the mouse the url is paste to textbox.

[MenuStrip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQrFF.png)

But when i click in right side, appear the menustrip of textbox. My question is I can disable this "menustrip"?!?

I send my code at the moment:

```
private void TxtUrl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
                TxtUrl.Paste();

        }
```

Comment: Set `TxtUrl.ShortcutsEnabled = false` before you call the `.Paste()` method. Re-enable the property in the `MouseUp` event to keep the keyboard's shortcuts. [`ShortcutsEnabled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.shortcutsenabled?view=net-5.0).

Comment: @dr.null thanks, dude.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your code:

```
    private MouseButtons e_Button = new MouseButtons();
    private void TxtUrl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        e_Button = e.Button;

        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            TxtUrl.Paste();
    }

    private void cms_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e_Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Comment: Solid Track, your code, isn't worked. But thanks to help me.